# Video codec error com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: Android studio

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I am working on video player with ExoPlayer library and my working fine but in some device I am getting Video codec error, even I have try to use software decoder, but still getting same problem in some device. Any can help me to resolve this issue?

here is my code

```
private void playVideo() {
        String path = mVideoFile.get(position).getPath();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        DefaultRenderersFactory rf = new DefaultRenderersFactory(this.getApplicationContext())
                .setExtensionRendererMode(DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_ON).setMediaCodecSelector(
                        new MediaCodecSelector() {
                            @Override
                            public List<MediaCodecInfo> getDecoderInfos(String mimeType,
                                                                        boolean requiresSecureDecoder, boolean requiresTunnelingDecoder)
                                    throws MediaCodecUtil.DecoderQueryException {
                                List<MediaCodecInfo> decoderInfos = MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT
                                        .getDecoderInfos(mimeType, requiresSecureDecoder, requiresTunnelingDecoder);
                                if (MimeTypes.VIDEO_H264.equals(mimeType)) {
                                    // copy the list because MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT returns an unmodifiable list
                                    decoderInfos = new ArrayList<>(decoderInfos);
                                    Collections.reverse(decoderInfos);
                                }
                                return decoderInfos;
                            }
                        });

        player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this, rf).build();
        DefaultDataSourceFactory defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "App")
        );

  
        concatenatingMediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource();
        for (int i = 0; i<mVideoFile.size(); i++){
            new File(String.valueOf(mVideoFile.get(i)));
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(defaultDataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(uri))));
            concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource);

            playerView.setPlayer(player);
            playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
            player.prepare(concatenatingMediaSource);
          //  player.seekTo(position, C.TIME_UNSET);

           playError();

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the format/container of the video file that you are trying to play?

Comment: I am trying to play .webm format files

Comment: webm encoded using VP9 is supported only on android 4.4+, you can see supported formats on different versions https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

Answer (score 0):

Video codec error arrises when you dont release your player properly.
Check the flow of exoplayer in the activtiy where you have initialised and where have released .Hence release the exoplayer before again initialising it with exoplayer.build.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).